# JavaScript click doesn't work the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, confirm

I have a jQuery script to delete a message. The first time I click the link everything works fine. I click the delete link and a `confirm` dialog appears. Upon confirmation it redirects to another page and then back. However, the second time I click the link nothing happens.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.del").click(function(){
        var conf = confirm("Confirmation message"); 
        if(conf == true)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    });
});
```

Click function must work every click event.

Comment: `if(x == true) return true; else return false;` - that's a WTF; simply write `return x;`

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/BBneU/ -- perhaps some other part of your code is causing a JavaScript error which is preventing any further code from running?

Comment: What does it mean to "del sth"? And what are you talking about with regards to first click, second click, directs, redirects? Why don't you set up the ***whole*** scenario and explain the ***whole*** sequence of events that behave contrary to your expectations.

Comment: The answer, whatever it is, is not in this code, but in all the other code you have. Does the a.del element perhaps get removed and recreated, without the document.ready being triggered again?

Comment: @ThiefMaster, he's relying on type coercion, but should just be using `return !!conf;`

Comment: How can you click it twice if it redirects after the first click?

Comment: @colin I suspect the same, he's probably dealing with html that is being removed, added. And the added anchor does not have the clickhandler attached. use .live or .delegate instead But he's not supplying enough code so hard to say for sure...

Comment: do you have multiple href having class del? if yes than bind your click to live method, i think it should work.

Comment: `confirm()` returns a boolean so no, he doesn't.

Answer (score -3):

I did it by not writing into $(document).ready(function(){});

Like:

```
$("a.del").click(function(){
    var conf = confirm("Confirmation message"); 
    if(conf == true)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
});
```

Comment: Just so you know, that's like having a sore leg, and chopping your leg off, claiming that your leg will no longer hurt that way.

Comment: Or like shooting the messenger.

Comment: Hey, I just ask a question, solved it and share with other people. I am trying it since 2 days. @davin I could not share the solution.

Comment: I know this is really late but the reason this is a bad idea is if you don't wait until the page is loaded before accessing a DOM element, you're creating a race condition.